# Yii2. Restrict access to images folder

Tags: yii2, access-control

I will show an example of what I would like to achieve. And I am curious how to implement this in `Yii2`.

There is a website `http://www.hleda-se-phpkar.cz/`. If I will `inspect` top main image I will see:

`<img src="images/leader.png" alt="">`

If I will write instantly to `address` line:

```
http://www.hleda-se-phpkar.cz/images/leader.png
```

I will see this picture `leader.png` in `browser`.

But if I will write:

```
http://www.hleda-se-phpkar.cz/images
```

I will see:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /images/ on this server.
```

So how to restrict access to the `folder` with images as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the mentioned restriction type and with Apache server all you need to do is create `.htaccess` file inside `folder` and add the line

```
Options -Indexes
```

and hit enter. This doesn't allow files listing but still allows files access. No special action from Yii 2 is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. It is exactly what I wanted!